# Esterification with tertiary alcohol

Tags: reaction-mechanism, alcohols, carbocation, esters

I saw a different mechanism for esterification of tertiary alcohol in a book.

They say that first the $\ce{OH}$ is protonated and it leaves to form the tertiary carbocation. Then the oxygen's lone pair from the carboxylic acid attacks to form the ester.

Is this mechanism actually correct?

Comment: It depends on the conditions used

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the mechanism is correct and is different from the normal mechanism because here the more stable tertiary carbocation formation.

Comment: Care to elaborate it?

Answer (score -3):

Upon esterification of a tertiary alcohol an **alkene** is formed as the major product, not an ester.